# Image gallery integration into web-page

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, gallery

I have a need to intagrate into a web page based on html and javascript (php and mysql are available), an image gallery and a panel from whom only administrator can upload pictures and add a little comment, which shows under the picture in gallery. So my question is - is there an open-source solution to my problem, I am asking here my question becuase I dont even know what to google, because as you can see English is not my first language.

Comment: There are photo galleries out there with admin panels and everything, but they tend to be self-contained stand-alone portals.  How many pictures are you dealing with? 10's, 100's, 1000's ?

Comment: i think no more than 500, maybe less

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try searching for "photo gallery php mysql" and see what you find.

For example, I found the following: http://www.plogger.org

You could also try a simple CMS like Perch CMS: https://grabaperch.com

With Perch, you could build the front-end to suit your client needs and still have a decent backend to upload the images and title/captions.